# PL/SQL: Unable to return value from Package elements PL/SQL

Tags: function, plsql, package, return-value

I have created a following package and package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE interest_calculation IS
interest_rate number(2,3) := 0.5;
FUNCTION interests (ID IN char)
RETURN number;
END interest_calculation;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY interest_calculation
IS 
FUNCTION interests
(ID IN char)
RETURN number
IS
CURSOR ecursor IS
    SELECT l.borrower_id, l.shiffer, l.date, l.return_date, r.price
    FROM loans l, books r   
    WHERE l.shiffer=r.shiffer AND borrower_id = ID;
kirje ecursor%ROWTYPE;
summed number(4,2) := 0;
interest number(4,2);
period integer;
BEGIN
FOR kirje IN ecursor LOOP
    period := kirje.return_date - kirje.date;
    IF period < 15 THEN
    interest := 0;
    ELSE
    interest := (period - 14) * kirje.price * (interest_rate/100) ;
    END IF;
    summed := summed + interest;
    END LOOP;
RETURN summed;
END;
END interest_calculation;
/
```

When I am calling the package function:

```
 execute interest_calculation.interests('37904010329');
```

I get an error:

```
    ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'INTERESTS' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Why is it not returning the function value ? Do I have to add a procedure to the package head so it would return the function value ?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The error message is clear: `INTERESTS' is not a procedure`. This is a **function**. You cannot call a function using `execute`. Try: `SELECT interest_calculation.interests('37904010329') FROM dual` or `DECLARE x NUMBER; BEGIN x:=interest_calculation.interests('37904010329'); DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( x ); END;`

Comment: This lost the error but it returned empty value although I tested the function separately before and should have returned a real number. I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use execute keyword for a procedure. In the package you have created a function. For getting the result, you should execute the function in the following format.

```
select interest_calculation.interests('37904010329') 
from dual;
```

A function must be called from a SQL or PL/SQL statement where the value returned by the function is utilized- i.e., assigned to a variable, passed as a parameter, etc.

Comment: But I now got an error: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large
ORA-06512: at "LTELLISKIVI.INTEREST_CALCULATION", line 2

Comment: I don't get it. It sometimes gives me the error and then sometimes returns no error and empty value...

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered. I got it working now.
Seems the problem was that interest_rate number(2,3) := 0.5; precision was too large and that was the reason it returned an empty value. Hence the error I got "PL/SQL numeric or value error: number precision too large". I also changed "ID in char" --> "ID in loans.borrower_ID%type " but I am not sure if that improved anything.